# How to return the position of a document, relative to the collection in MongoDB ( scalable )

Tags: mongodb

I'm looking for a solution to the following :

I have a sortable, paginated table representing collection in mongodb

To take the initial results and each page I use the following

```
var defaultRows = 10;
var defaultPage = 1;
var defaultSort = ['name'];
var page = defaultPage - 1;
var totalPages = Math.ceil(db.table.count() / defaultRows);

var results = db.table.find().skip(page * defaultRows).limit(defaultRows).sort(defaultSort);
```

So I'm searching for a solution of a search for document and returning the exact page of this document according to the sort variable.

I've came up with this, but it would not scale very well on large collections.

```
var counter = 0;
var page = 1;
var queryName = 'smth';
db.table.find().sort(defaultSort).forEach( function ( doc ) {
    if ( doc.name === query.Name ) return false;
    counter++;
    if ( counter === 10 ) { counter = 0; page++ };
});

print page;  // Here page will give me the correct page
```

But If I have a large table wouldn't it be wrong to parse it all through forEach and load it as collection? Is there any easier way to do that, which is more scalable.

*Of course this is raw mongo javascript console script, I'm using mongoosedb as node.js driver, but it looks very similar to this!

Comment: A MongoDB document doesn't have a position relative to the collection. Mongo is much like a traditional SQL server in this respect. For example, depending on if you were sorting by either name or age a given document could be both the first and last document in the collection at the same time. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to determine the position of a document according the given query in the returned collection array, without using forEach. That's it.

But it seems there is no other way, except this!

Comment: But why are you trying to determine the position of the document within the collection according to the query?

Comment: In my particular app, I have a paginated table in my UI and I want to know at which page is the added (edited) document, so I can display a notification about this page. I though of a new field called 'position', but it would be unpractical, because it will change everytime I sort the results!

Comment: If the document is being edited through the UI that is displaying the notification, then it's probably easier to track the position through the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know your usecase. You want to display a paginated list with a preselected item in the list. Aka, the correct page has to be found to load from mongo.

I used a different approach using something like this:

```
db.user.find({name: {$lt: "foo"}}).sort({name: 1}).count()
```

This will retrieve the poistion of the selected item using your selected sort.

Now you can calulate the correct page as before.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep track of any changes by using the unique document id. You should not use position in the result set as the identifier of the document.